# Infopath form not using source to redirect

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath, infopath2010

I have an InfoPath 2010 browser enabled form in a sharepoint 2010 environment. The form has a Save and Close button. When a userupdates a text box and clicks save the changes are registered to the field and the connecting to the server busy box appears, but the form acts as if the user did not click save because it was still processing the field update. So I created a view that the forms switches to when a user clicks close. This view has two buttons save and close and close without saving. The save and close button submits the form and close redirecting to the source, however the close button does not save the changes and produces the form has been closed message and does not redirect to the source.

Does anyone know how to get the close button on the second view to redirect to the source in the URL?

If I use the close button on the default view it redirects fine, but switching to the view and then closing does not.

Comment: Can you tell the action rule written in submit button of first view

Comment: for redirecting to URL you just try the hyperlink control

Comment: The submit button sets a bunch of values then submits to SharePoint library and then closes the form (close this form: No prompt)

Comment: You need both switching to secondview and close that form  automatically after switching to the second view in same button (button in default view).

Answer (score 0):

Try this.........

1.)Just Add the Button control

2.)In `Manage Rules`- Add new rule in `Action` rule type

3.)Under run this action add- `Close the from` (Close this form:No Prompt)

Comment: This is the current rule on the button. The only rule on the button is close the form (close this form:No Prompt)